# Filed error in object 'objname' on field:'fieldname' : rejected value [null];

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I'm a beginner and I'm tring to create an application that is similar to twitter

I have 3 domain classes i.e. user,tweets and followers.

Followers domain is maintain the link between two user to follow each other.

When I perform save() on the follower it throws the following error, I'm not able to figure out where im going wrong:

> Field error in object 'mail.Follower' on field 'follower': rejected value [null]; codes [mail.Follower.follower.nullable.error.mail.Follower.follower,mail.Follower.follower.nullable.error.follower,mail.Follower.follower.nullable.error.mail.User,mail.Follower.follower.nullable.error,follower.follower.nullable.error.mail.Follower.follower,follower.follower.nullable.error.follower,follower.follower.nullable.error.mail.User,follower.follower.nullable.error,mail.Follower.follower.nullable.mail.Follower.follower,mail.Follower.follower.nullable.follower,mail.Follower.follower.nullable.mail.User,mail.Follower.follower.nullable,follower.follower.nullable.mail.Follower.follower,follower.follower.nullable.follower,follower.follower.nullable.mail.User,follower.follower.nullable,nullable.mail.Follower.follower,nullable.follower,nullable.mail.User,nullable]; arguments [follower,class mail.Follower]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
>   Field error in object 'mail.Follower' on field 'user': rejected value [null]; codes [mail.Follower.user.nullable.error.mail.Follower.user,mail.Follower.user.nullable.error.user,mail.Follower.user.nullable.error.mail.User,mail.Follower.user.nullable.error,follower.user.nullable.error.mail.Follower.user,follower.user.nullable.error.user,follower.user.nullable.error.mail.User,follower.user.nullable.error,mail.Follower.user.nullable.mail.Follower.user,mail.Follower.user.nullable.user,mail.Follower.user.nullable.mail.User,mail.Follower.user.nullable,follower.user.nullable.mail.Follower.user,follower.user.nullable.user,follower.user.nullable.mail.User,follower.user.nullable,nullable.mail.Follower.user

this is my code

domain

```
package mail

class User {
    String name
    String email
    String password
    int age

static constraints = {
    name blank:false
    email blank:false
    password blank:false
    age blank:false

    }
static hasMany=[tweets:Tweets,followers:Follower]



}
```

followers domain

```
package mail

class Follower {
    User follower
static constraints = {
    follower nullable:false

}
static belongsTo=[user:User]


}
```

this is the follower controller

```
package mail
import grails.converters.JSON
class FollowerController {


static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update:"POST", delete:"POST",authenticate:"POST"]

def responseBody =[:]

def index() {}

def list(){
    render Follower.list(sort:"dateCreated",order:"desc") as JSON
}

def get(Long id)
{
    def followerInstace=Follower.get(id)
    render followerInstace as JSON
}

def save()
{
  def followerInstace=new Follower(request.JSON)
  def user=User.get(session.loggedInUser.id)
  println user
  if(followerInstace.save(flush:true))
  {
      user.addToUser(followerInstace.id)
      responseBody.message="saved successfully"
     responseBody.id=followerInstace.id
     responseBody.code=200
     render responseBody as JSON
     return
  }
  println followerInstace.errors
  responseBody.message="save not successfull"
   responseBody.code=400
  println responseBody
  render responseBody as JSON
}

def show(Long id)
{
    def followerInstance=Follower.get(id)
    if(followerInstance)
    {
        responseBody.code=200
        resoponseBody.mesage="file found"
        responseBody.followerInstance=followerInstance
        render responseBody as JSON
    }
    else
    {
        responseBody.code=404
        responseBody.message="Not Found"
        render responseBody as JSON
        return
    }
}


def delete(Long id)
{
    def followerInstace= Follower.get(id)
    followerInstace.delete()
    responseBody.message = "successfully deleted"
    render responseBody as JSON
}
def update(Long id,Long version)
{
    def followerInstance = Follower.get(id)
    followerInstance.properties = params

    if(followerInstance.save(flush:true))
    {
        responseBody.message="successfully updated"
        responseBody.code = 200
        responseBody.id = followerInstance.id
    }
    else {
        responseBody.code = 400
        responseBody.message = 'Some error(s) exist'
    }
    render responseBody as JSON
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in controller:

```
def followerInstace=new Follower(request.JSON)
  def user=User.get(session.loggedInUser.id)
  followerInstanse.follower = user
  if(followerInstace.save(flush:true))
  {...
```

This exception trows because field followers is null

Comment: now it says again

Field error in object 'mail.Follower' on field 'user': rejected value [null];

Comment: @ShreyasRaghunath then there is no user with the given id.  the result of the `User.get()` itself is null.  You have a println in your original code there, what does it print?

Comment: i had to log out and log in again, once i log in again it prints the id correctly

Comment: @ShreyasRaghunath do you have Spring Security plugin? If no, install it. And take user normally by springSecurityService.currentUser as User

Comment: @ Koloritnij  ya i will try it

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out in a simple way i sent an id to the save method instead of the whole object because it is the link between two users that i want to save...

```
def save(Long id)
{
  def followerInstace=new Follower(request.JSON)
  def user=User.get(session.loggedInUser.id)
  User use=User.get(id)
  followerInstace.followers=use
  followerInstace.user = User.get(session.loggedInUser.id)

  if(followerInstace.save(flush:true))
  {

      responseBody.message="saved successfully"
     responseBody.id=followerInstace.id
     responseBody.code=200
     render responseBody as JSON
     return
  }
  println followerInstace.errors
  responseBody.message="save not successfull"
   responseBody.code=400
  println responseBody
  render responseBody as JSON
}
```

and now i get the result stored correctly in the db